# issue in fetching data from hibernate using struts2

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, struts2

I am trying to fetch data from table which I am not getting anything but some errors in log file...please someone help me

catalina.2013-11-15.log

> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.521 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] < unknown >.< unknown > HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
>
> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.557 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.Final}
>
> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.568 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>
> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.577 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>
> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.693 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>
> 15-Nov-2013 11:13:32.696 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-2] null.null HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

GetAllUserAction.java

```
public String execute() {
    UserServiceDao userServiceDao = new UserServiceImpl();
    User user = new User();
    users = new ArrayList<User>();

    try {
        users = userServiceDao.fetchService();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return "SUCCESS";
}

public List getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(List users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
public List fetchService() throws Exception {
    UserDao userImpl ;
    List userList;

    try {
        userImpl = new UserImpl();
        userList = new ArrayList();
        userList = userImpl.getAllUser();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new Exception( "\nexception in user fetch service\n"+e );
      }  

    return userList;
 }
```

UserImpl.java

```
public List getAllUser() throws ClassNotFoundException,Exception{
    Session session = DataBaseConnection.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null; 
    List users = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        users = session.createQuery("from user").list();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new Exception("Exception in UserImpl " + e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return users;

}
```

User.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.ecommerce.hibernate.model.User" table="user">
<meta attribute="class-description">
    This class contains the user details.
</meta>
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
    <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="name">
    <column name="name" />
</property>
<property name="userName">
    <column name="username"/>
</property>
<property name="password">
    <column name="password"/>
</property>
<property name="phone">
    <column name="phone"/>
</property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="GetAllUserAction" class="com.ecommerce.action.GetAllUserAction">
<result name="SUCCESS">/GetUser.jsp</result>
</action>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property     name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySqlDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="com/ecommerce/model/User.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DatabaseConnection.java

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {

    try{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new serviceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();       
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch(HibernateException e) {
        throw new HibernateException( " \nSession factory"+e ); 
    }   

}
```

GetUser.jsp

```
<s:iterator value="users">
 <tr>
            <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="userName"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="password"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="contactNumber"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="address"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="city"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="email"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Table name:user

Comment: Is your hibernate.cfg.xml in the classpath?

Comment: yes it is in the classpath

Comment: exactly in the /src or WEB-INF/classes folder?

Comment: in C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5\webapps\HibernateExample1\WEB-INF\classes\hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: by default pool size is 20 and there's no limit in it, so it seems useless in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have few doubts on your code..

1) `users = session.createQuery("from **user**").list();`
    can you change user to **User** and try?

2)  `UserServiceDao userServiceDao = new UserServiceImpl();`

I dont think this is the right way of doing.. Is this the naming convention problem?

try

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: regarding your doubts:1)i changed to User that was a mistake done by myself.2)that too was wrong naming convention done by myself...thanks a lot .. but still the same problem persist

Comment: This might be silly question but here it comes.. how do u ensure that you are not getting any data from the query ?

Comment: I have also noticed that you have not mentioned data type for the properties in User.hbm.xml.I feel this is mandatory property (if i'm not wrong).